# Knockout - How to bind outer container css from set of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

OK, admittedly horrible grammar in the question, but here's the lowdown:

I'm using the following in my site:

- Twitter Bootstrap
- Knockout
- Durandal

I'm trying to add a css class to the outer label surrounding a checkbox (in a list of checkboxes) so it can highlight the selected checkboxes. Essentially the code is this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:values">
    <label class="checkbox inline btn" data-bind="css: { }">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: text }, checked: $parent.checkedValues" /> 
        <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to add the btn-primary class to the outer label for the checkboxes that are checked.  Rather than put the full viewmodel in here, I've created a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/riceboyler/WEPRZ/1/

I recognize that I can use the $data object to get the current item, but I can't figure out how to check and see if the current item ($data.text) is in the checkedValues observableArray. I'm sure it's probably basic Javascript that I'm missing, but is there any way to do this without using a computed value?

Comment: I didn't know that you could populate an array of items using the `checked` binding like that.  That's handy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly in the `css` binding by inspecting the parent's checkedValues array.

```
<label 
    class="checkbox inline btn" 
    data-bind="css: {'btn-primary': $parent.checkedValues.indexOf(text) > -1}">
```

[**See the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/WEPRZ/3/)

Comment: Superb!  Thanks so much for easy and succinct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this predicate :

```
$parent.checkedValues().indexOf($data.text) >= 0
```

I created a [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/WEPRZ/2/) your fiddle.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is really close - the only thing here is including the parentheses `checkedValues()` uses the underlying JS array.  As a result, it depends on the Array prototype having an `indexOf` function.  Some browsers don't support this, including IE <9.  A better choice is to use the observableArray's `indexOf` function, which is built-in.

Comment: You are right I didn't think of that.
Thanks for your comment.