# knockout checkbox selection based on parent div

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to have a checkbox bound with knockout so that when I click on the surrounding div it selects the checkbox.

Below is what I'm after, but the click event only works when you click the div (not the checkbox). I think that this is because both the click and the actual checkbox selection event are occurring.

```
<div class="checkbox-row" data-bind="click: toggleSelected">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" />
    <div data-bind="text: title"></div>
</div>

ko.applyBindings(new (function () {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable('some text');
    self.selected = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleSelected = function() {
        self.selected(!self.selected());
        return false;
    };
}));
```

This is similar to the following question: [Knockout - How to bind outer container css from set of checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319892/knockout-how-to-bind-outer-container-css-from-set-of-checkboxes)

However the solution proposed is to wrap the checkbox and content in a label, which works but I dont want to do this as i have quite a bit of content to fit in the row and a label is quite restrictive.

Is there an alternative way to create this behavior?

http://jsfiddle.net/BgFe9/

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution? Your fiddle seems to work fine...

Comment: @nemesv click on the actual checkbox, ive updated the question too

Comment: I know a solution but it is not nice: you need an empty `click` binding on the checkbox and set the `clickBubble: false` : http://jsfiddle.net/pJuM5/

Comment: @nemesv thanks that's a better solution than using a label, its workable even if its not tidy. I'm still really keen to know if anyone has a tidier one. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround (which is not too nice) is to define an "empty" click binding on the checkbox and set the `clickBubble: false`.

This will prevent the calling of the `toggleSelected` method when clicking directly on the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected, 
                                  click: function() { return true; }, 
                                  clickBubble: false" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pJuM5)